# Embed not settings image and thumnail

Tags: discord.js

When a user joins the server the bot will send an embed. Everything works fine except the image and thumbnail.

```
Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Welcome ***${member.displayName}***`)
.setColor("#2163D7")
.addFields({ name: `**${member.displayName}**`, value: 'Please read the **rules**'},{ name: `You are our ` , value: `***${member.guild.memberCount}*** member!`})    
.setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
.setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL)
console.log(member.user.avatarURL);

let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "┊");
channel.send(embed);
});
```

[Image of what it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S3fQ.png)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Discord JS v12, `avatarURL` is a method. So you'll have to use:

```js
member.user.avatarURL()
```